# Is there a way of a inserting blank datetimefield from another table?

Tags: python, django, model

```
class Customer(models.Model):

    last_purchase = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

I have a blank DateTimeField, which will continuously update itself with the last modified DateTimeField in the corresponding table.

```
class Order(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete= models.SET_NULL)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
```

How will this look on views?

Comment: Does your `Order` has a `ForeignKey` to the `Customer`?

Comment: Yes, it does.  I will update it

Answer (score 0):

Please do **not** duplicate data. Storing the same data, or aggregates of data is often an anti-pattern. It turns out that keeping data in sync is harder than one expects this to be. It means that if an `Order` is created, updated, removed, or changes from `Customer`, you have to update the related `Customer`. It is easy to overlook a few cases, to reach inconsistency.

What is often better is to make use of [**`.annotate(..)`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#annotate) to annotate your queryset. So if you remove the `last_purchase` field from the customer, and the `Order` has a `ForeignKey` to the customer:

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    # …

class Order(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

then we can make a `QuerySet` that looks like:

```
from django.db.models import Max

Customer.objects.annotate(
    last_purchase=Max('order__date_created')
)
```

This will be `None` (`NULL`) if the `Customer` has not made any order.

If you need this often, you can define the logic in a `Manager`:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Max

class CustomerManager(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).annotate(
            last_purchase=Max('order__date_created')
        )

class Customer(models.Model):
    # …
    objects = CustomerManager()

class Order(models.Model):
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Now it will automatically annotate the objects when you use `Customer.objects`.

This will make a query that looks like:

```
SELECT customer.*
       MAX(order.date_created) AS last_purchase
FROM   customer
```

You can of course perform extra filtering.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, I tried the Queryset, however it gave me a list of customers in ascending order, rather than the last recorded date coming from the orders table. I seem to get errors if I try to migrate when using CustomerManager()

Comment: @kamcoder: a manager does *not* require a migration. Removing the `last_purchase` field might indeed trigger a migration. The queryset will indeed give a list of customers, and these customers will have an extra attribute `.last_purchase`, so as if they have a field (but it is not a field).

Comment: Thanks, is there a way of knowing on how the last_purchase will return the latest datetimefield from order for each customer?

Comment: @kamcoder: yes, you can inspect the query generated by a queryset with `print(myqueryset.query)`, for example `print(Customer.objects.all().query)`. It will use an aggregate function in the database.

Comment: What do you mean by inspecting the query? how would look in this case?